# Org-mode: Is there a variable for a tags list like org-done-keywords is there for done todo keywords?

Tags: org-mode

`org-tag-alist` will list tags exactly as they are defined in the .emacs or init file, e.g.

```
((:startgroup . nil) ("@computer" . ?c) ("@phone" . ?p) ("@home" . ?h) (:endgroup . nil))
```

Is there a variable that "cleans" this format so that the tags are easily accessible as a list?

```
("@computer" "@phone" "@home")
```

This is similar to how `org-done-keywords` will parse (though it'll only take the done keywords) the much messier `org-todo-keywords` (which is a list of sequences).

Comment: How about using the function `org-global-tags-completion-table`?  See also the function `org-get-buffer-tags`.

Comment: Those seem to be close, but there seems to be extra stuff for inherited tags, .e.g `((#("parent" 0 2 (inherited t))) ("@phone") ...)`. I'd guess one would still have to write a function to parse the tags from this format as a list?

Comment: Also, a bit offtopic, but what does the `#` mean in front of the list for the inherited tag? Is it equivalent to the same list without the hash sign?

Comment: I got the two functions from what `org-tags-view` uses as it relates to potential tag completions, and I suspect there are some additional functions already in existence that further parse the results from the functions mentioned in the first comment.  Once you find them, that should save you the trouble of writing your own function.  I don't have any inherited tags in my setup, so I couldn't answer that question without guessing about things like arrays and text properties -- sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything else in org-agenda.el or org.el that stored the tags in the way I wanted, but it turned out it was relatively easy to write the function to do so.

The `#(...)` format was apparently just a text property, so the function was as simple as (as long as you don't mind the property still there in the list)...

```
(defun org-get-all-tags-list ()
    (interactive)        
    (mapcar 'car (org-global-tags-completion-table)))
```